# In Android, are we need to get internet service in SIM when we get geo data?

Tags: java, android

In android app i have code to get Geo data through GPS or Network. Which one is enable the geo data will get through that. If i switch off the GPS, then the Geo data will get through the Network.

for that Are we need to get Internet access through cell tower for get Geo data through network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need Internet connectivity to use the NETWORK_PROVIDER though. Without Internet connection you won't get an updated position.